# How to find the sub-directories using find

Tags: bash, shell, perl, csh, tcsh

I'm using this below command to get the sub-directories inside an array @handoff of a perl code.

```
chomp(@handoff = `find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -name "18????_????" | sort -u | tail -2`);
```

I'm getting the error as

```
find: unknown predicate `-lrt'
```

If I try the same command in terminal directly, I'm able to get the sub-directories. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Is there a file called `-lrt` in the filesystem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that in the filesystem.

Comment: Don't use `find` for this at all; just use the `glob` function: `@handoff = glob("18????_????"/)`.

Comment: It's caused by `find *` and a file named `-lrt`. Maybe `find . -maxdepth 1`?

Answer (score 2):

No need to call an external program to find sub-directories:

```
opendir(my $dh, '.') || die "Can't opendir '.': $!";
my @handoff = grep { /^18.{4}_.{4}$/ && -d $_ } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
print join(' ', @handoff), "\n"
```

Comment: I would put the `-d` check before the regex check. That way, you're only doing the regex check on directories only, as opposed to running it against all files and directories.

Comment: @stevieb Flip side: Filename is already in memory for the regex.  `-d` requires a stat call.  Time to break out the benchmarks....

Answer (score 0):

find expects the path to search as first argument, hence :

```
    find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -name "18????_????" | sort -u | tail -2
```

should be :

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "18????_????" | sort -u | tail -2
```

(assuming that you want to search the current path - else replace the `.` with the path to search).

But bottom line, as you are using perl already, why use an external command like `find` ?

Here is another solution using module [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule).

```
use Path::Iterator::Rule;
my @handoffs = Path::Iterator::Rule
    ->new
    ->directory             # only directories (not files)
    ->max_depth(1)          # do not recurse
    ->name("18????_????")   # match directory name (glob or regex)
    ->all(".")              # search the current path
;
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks nifty. Unfortunately `Path::...` aren't core modules, so `File::Find` might be a better option.

Comment: Isn't the `use Path::Tiny` superfluous in your example?

Comment: @StefanBecker : thanks, removed the use of Path::Tiny